# python 3 bs4 how to select span value under certain divs

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Using python3 and bs4 I am having problems selecting two spans values under two different divs.

I want to achieve the following.

1.) Under the lastPriceChg div select the "chg chgUp" value. NOTE: This may alternatively be "chg chgDown". i.e.

```
<div class="lastPriceChg"><span class="price">0.023</span><span class="chg chgUp">0.0001 (0.44%)</span></div>
```

2.) There are multiple "panel" divs but I want the volumeFormatted value. i.e.

```
<div class="panel">
                <strong glossaryid="volume">Volume</strong>
                <span class="value" val="volumeFormatted">3,851,529</span>
                <strong class="under">Dividend</strong>
                <span class="value"><span formatcall="toPrice" val="dividend">N/A</span></span>
            </div>
```

What is really strange is if I paste the webpages html into a html_doc it works...

Here is my non-working current code:

```
url = ('https://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/VDRM/quote')
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

for item in soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'value'}):
    print(item.text.strip()
```

Sample out of just volume:

```
$ python scraper.py 
Get Change


 - 
 -
```

The following does work:

```
html_doc = """
<div class="panel">
                <strong glossaryid="volume">Volume</strong>
                <span class="value" val="volumeFormatted">3,105,009</span>
                <strong class="under">Dividend</strong>
                <span class="value"><span formatcall="toPrice" val="dividend">N/A</span></span>
            </div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

for item in soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'value'}):
    print(item.text.strip()
```

Sample out of just volume:

```
$ python scraper.py 
Get Change
3,105,009
N/A
```

So why does this not work when actually reading from the website?

edit: Here is a screen shot from inspector of the span classes I am looking for:
[inpect screen shot of spans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIfbY.png)

Comment: When I examined the HTML in the url you provided I was unable to find any of these strings: 'lastPriceChg', 'chgUp', 'chgDown'. Are you confident that your question is correctly specified?

Comment: Yes @BillBell . Did you hit the main page or use the direct link for a ticker symbol like otcmarkets.com/stock/VDRM/quote? These values are under the quoteData div class. I will post a screen shot as well.

Comment: I used the address in your Python name `url`, in your 'non-working current code'.

Comment: If you use the following code you'll see the parent divs. `url = ('https://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/VDRM/quote')
 page = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
 soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
 divs = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'id': 'quoteContent'})
 for div in divs:
  print (div)` lastPriceChg is located under the div priceChgBBO @BillBell

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, the stuff you want really doesn't appear in the page that I receive. I imagine that it's because you live in a different geopolitical region. This is what the interesting area of the HTML looks like for me.[image: contents of div missing] Beyond that the text for the other items is empty too.

No matter. I added in the HTML from your image for what was missing in the first `div` and I can show how to get what you want for the second part of your question without the need to do that.

I open the file of HTML with the stuff added in. The main thing I would say to you is that you can specify which `span` elements you want fairly directly in the following way.

```
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open('temp.htm').read(),'lxml')
>>> spans = soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'chg'})
>>> spans[0].text
'0.0022 (9.17%)'
>>> spans_2 = soup.findAll('span', attrs={'val': 'dividend'})
>>> spans_2[0].text
'\n'
```

Unfortunately I cannot guarantee that this will work for you.

Comment: I guess thats my question, or roadblock. I dont understand why the data is not there. Maybe this has to do with the javascript in the page? I found a alternative source for this data which works properly.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment here is the new code using the alternative source. Its a lot easier then I thought now that I am actually getting return data. =)

```
url = ('http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/vdrm')
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
vol = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'volume last-value'})
volume = vol.text.strip()
chg = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'change--percent--q'})
change = chg.text.strip()
print ("Vol: {} Change: {}".format(volume, change))
```